# Parenthesis Operation in PEMDAS Python

Tags: python

This function works as the Parenthesis operation in PEMDAS. I already have the PEMDAS Function working okay for the EMDAS operations, and this is the only operation I need to correct for my PEMDAS function to work okay.

It works for nested cases `(1+(1+1))` as we well as multiple, separated cases `(1+1) + (1+1)`. However, it doesn't work with the combination of the two `(1+(1+1)) + (1+1)`. How can I modify the code so that it can take the last case into account? **Note: We're not allowed to use regex.**

```
def paren(equation):
    for i in range(len(equation)):
        if equation[i] == "(":
            for j in range(i + 1, len(equation)):
                if equation[j] == ')':
                    return equation[i + 1:j]
                elif equation[j] == '(':
                    for x in range(len(equation) - 1, -1, -1):
                        if equation[x] == ')':
                            return equation[i + 1:x]
                else:
                    continue
```

SAMPLES:

- Input1: `(1+(1+1))`
- Output1: `1+(1+1)`
- Input2: `(1+1) + (2+2)`
- Output2: `1+1` (outputted the eq from the first bracket so that it can be solved first)
- Input3: `(1+(1+1)) + (1+1)`
- EXPECTED Output3: `1+(1+1)`
- Output3: `1+(1+1)) + (1+1`

Comment: I fail to see the pemdas operation you speak of in your code. Please give example input. A [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is pivitable to getting the best answer.

Comment: Ok I'll edit and add sample inputs and outputs

Comment: use a stack for matching parens

Comment: @JoranBeasley sorry I'm a bit new to python, how does stack work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for your test case. I count the numbers of open parentheses to find where to close the first equation.

```
def paren2(equation):
    equation = equation.replace(' ', '')
    open_parentheses_index_ = -1
    open_parentheses_count_ = 0
    close_parentheses_count_ = 0
    for i in range(len(equation)):
        if equation[i] == "(":
            if open_parentheses_index_ == -1:
                open_parentheses_index_ = i 
            open_parentheses_count_ += 1
        elif equation[i] == ")":
            close_parentheses_count_ += 1
            if open_parentheses_count_ == close_parentheses_count_:
                return equation[open_parentheses_index_+1 : i]
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I was able to apply also to my PEMDAS function and it's working now! Thanks.